# Installation without splashscreen / headless

Tags: installation

I recently pulled a computer out of storage that has a faulty video card. It still displays standard 80x25 terminal screens fine, but anything beyond that causes the video card to fail and require rebooting. As I intend to use this as a headless server, I'm not really interested in buying a new video card just for the installation.

The problem I run into is that Ubuntu - including the Server and Alternate installers - kick you to a (comparatively) high-res splashscreen that causes my video card to turn off, even though the rest of the install process uses a 80x25 TUI.

I've tried preseeding, but I have no experience with that and not having feedback makes my life difficult.

As I see it, there are (at least) two ways to accomplish this, neither of which I can find a way to accomplish:

- Pass a parameter that starts SSH (or VNC) and operate the install from another machine.
- Disable the high-resolution splash screen.
- Some other method that I haven't thought of.

I would prefer to use Ubuntu Server, but I'm not married to it. For what it's worth, every other distro I've tried (Debian, CentOS, Arch) also have high-res splashscreens. The only one that does, in fact, work is FreeNAS, but I'd strongly prefer a Linux variant over BSD.

Comment: @cgubuntu: It doesn't hang, but the graphics card fails. Repeatedly hitting enter, for example, will configure the network card to a point where I can see it as an attached device on the router.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Ok, as quickly as you can after you know that you are about to get to the splash screen, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The timing here is critical as your video card is about to fail.
2. This will drop you into a Text Mode Interface. You will now see a prompt that says `Boot:`. Type this exactly into the Prompt:

`/install/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz -- nomodeset`

This will now boot you into the installer.

Good luck

Comment: @ZackSheffler you were able to reach the network configuration step?

Comment: I can (in theory) get all the way through installation if I knew what series of keyboard inputs to execute. If there were a way to tell GRUB to boot into standard console mode instead of the VGA splash screen, I could see what's going on and not need further assistance.

Comment: when you get to a screen with a pink background, does your card fail?

Comment: No. When the GRUB bootloader puts a VGA resolution image on the screen, the card fails. As per the question, I need a way to disable the splashscreen or install the OS headless.

Comment: I got the answer up